# contempt formula when talking about something

Tags: expression-choice, figures-of-speech

What is the figure of speech that should be used to express contempt of something?

I tried this expression and I don't know if it is suitable for that context:

**Main phrase:**

> You had proposed XXX to our team .  (XXX is a tools for IT team)

**Attempt:**

> You had proposed a project management tools **which is called** XXX.

Comment: Do you mean 'content' or 'contempt' ?

Comment: contempt =abasement

Comment: @Abdennour: I do not understand your question, but I *can* tell you that *contempt* does not mean *abasement*. At your vocabulary level, you should probably be asking your questions on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but even there you would need to give a much clearer explanation of what you actually want to express.

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about "total bomb?"

**bomb**: *informal* : a disastrous failure: the new play was a total bomb!

> "*you had proposed a project management tool which is a total bomb*."

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for, you may say:

You had proposed a project management tool which is **a complete failure.**